# Controller async/await deadlock in SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a controller receiving multiple POST (1000 per minute) from multiple machines and due to that all these data are not inserted in the SQL database and generate some deadlocks.

How can I lock this method to be used synchronously to insert one after one instead of all at same time ?

I am able to reproduce the issue with this test controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Value1,Value2,Id")] Test test)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Tests.Add(test);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

EDIT : This code worked like a charm thanks to Peter answer. No deadlock. Performance was good and no slowness noticed.

```
private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Value1,Value2,Id")] Test test)
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Tests.Add(test);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    _semaphore.Release();
    db.Dispose();

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `ConfigureAwait(false)` when awaiting the task?

Comment: @PeterBruins what does `ConfigureAwait` has anything to do with this? Also op is talking about deadlock in SQL Server not in .NET code. And also `ConfigureAwait` is not solution to all problems.

Comment: You mean await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) ? I will give a try and let you know.

Comment: where you created instance of db

Comment: What kind of "deadlocks" are you seeing. A hanging client, or errors from SQL server about deadlocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `SemaphoreSlim` to limit the access to the database. This Semaphore can be awaited asynchously.

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);    

public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Value1,Value2,Id")] Test test)
{
    try{
        await semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.AuditTests.Add(test);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }finally{
        semaphore.release();
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

`try`-`finally` is used to make sure the lock is always released, even if e.g. the database call fails.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Would be possible to tell me how to implement SemaphoreSlim in my code ?

Comment: It worked like a charm, 20 000 posts done and 20 000 records in the DB.